# How to specify icons in manifest.json?

Tags: android, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, manifest, progressive-web-apps

How to specify the icons in manifest.json? It seems like some use an array and some use a dictionary. For example:

> https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple
>
> ```
> "icons": {
>    "128": "icon_128.png"
> },
> ```

But in this  source, they use it like this:

> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android?hl=en

```
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
```

If I try to install my web app as a chrome extension, and I use the latter format, I get this error:

[image]

So I guess I need to use the first format, for that. However, if I try to install my app as a progressive web app in android, the later format seems required ...

Comment: If I understand things, "web-apps"="chrome-apps"≠"chrome-extensions".  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Teepeemm So I have a web app. Just a website I guess you could say, just an url, people can type in the browser. So I want people to install this to their home on android. But I also want it in the Chrome Web Store.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple

> Got a web app? Follow this tutorial to add your existing web app to the Chrome Web Store.

According to that link

Comment: How this is related to Android? Please remove unnecessary tags.

Comment: @ReazMurshed It is about which manifest syntax you need to install a progressive web app in android.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is you need both. They are two different manifest files that are used for different purposes and live in different places.

For the Chrome Web Store you will create a manifest locally on your computer following the [getting started tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple). That manifest and the icon image will get added to a zip file and uploaded to the store.

```
"icons": {
  "128": "icon_128.png"
}
```

For [installable web apps](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android) you have to create a manifest file, uploaded it to your website along with the images, and then update your HTML pages to link to the manifest on your website.

```
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Is it allowed to place the manifest.json not in the root? We have placed the manifest.json and the icons in `content/icons/..` What will be the icon src then?

Comment: `src` is relative to the directory where `manifest.json` is. So if you have img `foo.png` in `img` than you would use `"src": "img/foo.png"`.